# how to update rbenv with chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm installing `ruby` by `rbenv` by using `chef` with fnichol' cookbook.

#### Berksfile

```
cookbook 'rbenv', github: 'fnichol/chef-rbenv'
```

#### nodes/mynode.json

```
"rbenv": {
    "user_installs": [
        { "user": "deployer",
          "rubies": ["2.0.0-p451"],
          "global": "2.0.0-p451"
        }
    ]
}
```

I could install without problem, but when it comes to updating I have a problem.

By adding `2.1.4`, I got error `ruby-build: definition not found: 2.1.4`. Apparently I must update rbenv, but I couldn't find the way to update rbenv by using `Chef`.

As a temporary solution I'm updating rbenv manually.

Does anyone know how to update rbenv from `Chef`?

Answer (score 1):

All I had to was to add the following lines to `nodes/mynode.json` to config auto upgrading `ruby_build`.

```
"ruby_build": {
"upgrade": true
},
```